# How to test logic in joined promises/then

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to write a test for an action handler on one of my components.  I am stubbing out the `save` method on one of my models to return a resolved promise using `Em.RSVP.Promise.resolve()`

in my component, i chain on that promise using `then`:

`return target
    .save()
    .then(function(){
        selected.rollback();
        this.sendAction('quicklinkChanged', target);
    }.bind(this),this.notify_user_of_persistence_error.bind(this, 'Save As'));`

this is a pattern that i use a lot server-side where we use `when` for our promise library.  however, when i do this client-side, i never end up inside the function in the `then` block so i cannot assert any of the functionality there in my unit tests.

can anyone provide any insight on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

We moved our callbacks out of the method so we could call them separately and verify functionality, or replace them and verify they were called.

#### Controller Example:

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  randomProperty: 1,
  async: function(fail){
    return new Em.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if(fail){
        reject('fdas');
      }else{
        resolve('foo');  
      }
    });
  },
  doAsyncThing: function(fail){
    return this.async(fail).then(this.success.bind(this), this.failure.bind(this));
  },
  success: function(){
    this.set('randomProperty', 2);
  },
  failure: function(){
    this.set('randomProperty', -2);
  }
});
```

#### Tests

```
test("async success", function(){
  var ic = App.IndexController.createWithMixins();
  stop();
  ic.doAsyncThing(false).then(function(){
    start();
    equal(ic.get('randomProperty'), 2);
  });

});

test("async fail", function(){
  var ic = App.IndexController.createWithMixins();
  stop();
  ic.doAsyncThing(true).then(function(){
    start();
    equal(ic.get('randomProperty'), -2);
  });

});

test("async success is called", function(){
  expect(1);
  var ic = App.IndexController.createWithMixins();
  ic.success = function(){
    ok(true);
  };
  stop();
  ic.doAsyncThing(false).then(function(){
    start();
  });

});

test("async failure is called", function(){
  expect(1);
  var ic = App.IndexController.createWithMixins();
  ic.failure = function(){
    ok(true);
  };
  stop();
  ic.doAsyncThing(true).then(function(){
    start();
  });

});

test("doAsyncThing returns a promise", function(){
  expect(1);
  var ic = App.IndexController.createWithMixins();
  ok(ic.doAsyncThing(true).then);

});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wipo/37/edit